# Install Java plugin for IE without manual update or install

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I have a client machine with JRE installed. Now i see the problem that java plugin is not installed in IE. Is there anyway i could manually register java plugin for IE without using installer or java update ? would it be possible to use command line argument or such alternative please let me know.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using the installer?

Comment: Its a client machine. And it is restricted to install or update any software.

Comment: Lets start with the basics.  What version of Java is installed?

Comment: The client machine is installed with Java 7 32 bit.

Comment: I need to know the specific version of Java 7 installed.

Comment: The client machine is installed with 1.7.0_51

Comment: Just enabled `Java content in the browser` featured located in the Java Control Panel and Java content within IE will be enabled.

Comment: I tried that option. But this will not install plugin.

Comment: IE doesn't use a plugin to enable Java content within a browser, it uses the control panel, and if you have that option enabled then Java content can be accessed within IE.  Only Chrome and Firefox require a plugin to enable Java content within them.  If it doesn't work then there is some other configuration option preventing it.  **In other words you already have a "plug-in" installed for IE**  You just need allow the content

Comment: I agree. But after using java control panel and enabling java content I could not see java plugin installed in IE addon. Typically when you install JRE you can see java plugin in manage addon screen in IE. But this did not work either

Comment: I also tried with ssvhelper.exe in bin folder of JRE installation path.

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on. If enabling Java content within a browser isn't actually enabling it then it cannot be done with IT's support.